# Biometric verification match-on-card

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-core, biometrics

I need to implement bio-metric verification mach on card ([Smart Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card)).

Basically:

1. Put your finger on a fingerprint reader and get fingerprint information.
2. Read a QR code and store information
3. Finally send the fingerprint information and the QR code to the 'chip of the card' and in response the chip returns if the verification is correct or not.

This I need to do for Xamarin forms and Windows form (.net core), I found a component to read the QR code for Xamarin forms, but I have not found any library that allows me to read the fingerprint and less how to verify with the chip of the card.

Have any of you implemented this? Do you have an example to guide me with?

Comment: on iOS and Android the o/s manages the fingerprint reader and does not expose any of it's information for use by external apps

Comment: Can you please provide your research (by [edit]ing your question), there's video's on youtube and resources easily searchable such as https://github.com/anotherlab/Xamarin-ACS-Smartcard-USB otherwise we'll no doubt repeat the research you've already done. Cheers